# Updating ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

**UPDATE:**
Based on Slace's response I am now using the latest Official release witch includes the functionality I am after however I am still getting the same issue below.

Gday All,

I am developing an App that uses the calendar pop up position that in not in the release build of ASP.NET Ajax. I have updated ASP.NET ajax to the latest dev release and when I create a new application with the functionality I require, it works perfectly.

However in the application I am trying to update it is not working.

I believe this is because I need to update the Javascript files that my application is using (IE CalendarBehavior.js). However I cant find the location of these files.

Where would these files be located and how do I updated the ASP.NET Ajax to the latest version so I can use the CalendarPositon element?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Righto,

I managed to get to the solution myself with a little input from Slace. It turned out that the was some major version issues on my PC. So I did a uninstall of all ASP.NET Ajax components and a reinstall using the latest official release. Which fixed the issues I was describing and allowed me to access the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not within the current release of the AJAX Control Toolkit I wouldn't expect that it would work. It may be only partially implemented, or only just started. I'd strongly suggest that you only use the official releases (of which there was one the other day).

That said, you can set the `ScriptPath` property to specify where you want the JS to be located.

Comment: Gday Slace. The feature I am looking to use works in the example application shipped with ASP.NET Ajax. So i need to update my version to the latest dev release. It should be as simple as overriding the old with the new but I cant find the old js files to overwrite.